# MailChimp API V3 GET

Tags: vba, ms-access, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm working with the MailChimp API v3.0 to link a small Access 2016 database into MailChimp with VBA - I'm using the following code to check if an email exists on MailChimp, and then get the subscriber status on a test list I've set up. However, it's not returning the correct subscription status:

```
Select Case Request
Case Is = "GET"
MailExist = False
MailSub = False
APIString = "search-members?query="
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open Request, APIUrl & APIString & Criteria, False
    .setrequestheader "Authorization", "Basic " & APIAuth
    .send
    APIResponse = .responsetext
    If InStr(APIResponse, "{""exact_matches"":{""members"":[]") > 0 Then
        MailExist = False
        Else
        MailExist = True
        Set JSONControl = CreateObject("MSScriptControl.ScriptControl")
        JSONControl.language = "Jscript"
        APIString = "lists/a0da306709/members/"
        .Open Request, APIUrl & APIString & StringMD5(Criteria), False
        .setrequestheader "Authorization", "Basic " & APIAuth
        .send
        Debug.Print "CONTACT STATUS IS: " & .responsetext; Spc(2)
        Set Subber = JSONControl.Eval("(" + .responsetext + ")")
        If Subber.status = "subscribed" Then
            MailSub = True
            Else
            MailSub = False
        End If
    End If
End With
End Select
```

The above is currently returning a "status":"subscribed" in the body of the response text, but when I log into MailChimp and view the actual contact their status is 'unsubscribed' (I'm the one who unsubscribed them via the API). I've checked the the MD5 hash to identify the email is correct and I'm not getting any error responses from MailChimp, so I'm at a loss as to why the response shows the account as 'Subscribed'...

Comment: Sounds like an issue you should direct to MailChimp customer support. If their API is not returning the correct data, we can't help you.

Comment: After a bit more testing I can see that MailChimp isn't receiving a GET call that is a repeat of an earlier one. Viewing the 'Last 24 hours of API calls' on MailChimp, the calls I'm making to get subscriber status for a contact I've previously made a GET call for are not showing up at all. Closing and re-opening the database appears to confirm this, as the same code run for the same contact after re-opening shows up as a GET call on the mailchimp API calls record. Perhaps I need to destroy the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object?

Comment: Eh... You're creating a new XMLHTTP object with your `With` statement. Every time you run this code, you're generating a new API call. Mailchimp might cache calls and return cached results, however, but that again is a customer support question.

Comment: Ok, I think I've found the fix for this - it appears to be the XMLHTTP object that was the problem, as creating a 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP' object instead allows me to make multiple GET calls and receive a correct response, along with the call being registered at MailChimp's end correctly. Stumped as to why though!